# Бесконечный цикл layoutSubviews для TextView

Tags: ios, textview

Я использую в своем проекте библиотеку JVFloatLabeledTextField. Раньше воспроизводил на реальном устройстве, но на симуляторе тоже воспроизводится (пробовал на iPhone 7 plus iOS 10.2). Если ввести какой-то текст в texView, затем выделить текст и нажать на "Скопировать все", то приложение зависает, бесконечно вызывается layoutSubviews.

Я попробовал исправить проблему и создал кастомные класс для textView. В нем переопределял метод intrinsicContentSize, но тогда возникают другие сложности. Помогите решить проблему, не хотелось отказываться от библиотеки. Тестовый проект залил в репозиторий: 
https://github.com/ed8009/textView-With-JVFloatLabeledTextView

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
if (!self.scrollEnabled && !CGSizeEqualToSize(self.bounds.size, [self intrinsicContentSize])) {
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

}

https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField/issues/187